# Open folder with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody help me with this code?
How can I open the existing folder?

```
Sub click button()
    Dim folderpath As String
    folderpath = "c:\"
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
    Dim col As Range

    For Each col In rng.Rows
        If Dir(folderpath + CStr(col.Rows), vbDirectory) = "" Then
            Dim response
            response = MsgBox("Folder:" & col.Rows & " doesnt exist. Do you want to create it?", vbYesNo, "Folder")
            If response = vbYes Then
                MkDir (folderpath + CStr(col.Rows))
            End If 
        Else
            MsgBox "Folder:" & col.Rows & " exists"
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Shell function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx):

```
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & folderpath + CStr(col.Rows) & "", vbNormalFocus
```

In full:

```
Sub click button()
    Dim folderpath As String
    folderpath = "c:\"
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
    Dim col As Range

    For Each col In rng.Rows
        If Dir(folderpath + CStr(col.Rows), vbDirectory) = "" Then
            Dim response
            response = MsgBox("Folder:" & col.Rows & " doesnt exist. Do you want to create it?", vbYesNo, "Folder")
            If response = vbYes Then
                MkDir (folderpath + CStr(col.Rows))
            End If 
        Else
            response = MsgBox("Folder:" & col.Rows & " exists. Do you want to open it?", vbYesNo, "Folder")
            If response = vbYes Then
                 Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & folderpath + CStr(col.Rows) & "", vbNormalFocus
            End if
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: can i response withe yes or no?

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer it's works! i mean If user don't want to open the folder

Comment: Do the same as you've done already where you ask them if they want to create a folder. response = MsgBox etc, if response = vbYes then use the shell command

Comment: @Absinthe You can use the `explorer.exe` without specifying the path or using `Shell environ("windir") & "\explorer.exe "` to improve it for the case that a windows directory was not installed on `C:\ `

Comment: IT'S WORKING PERFECT! Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know how can i open the folder in the same windows explorer every time?

Comment: No, sorry. Perhaps you should ask it as a new question.